# lookbehind with random string - workaround?

Tags: regex, wildcard, lookbehind

following scenarios:

```
stringN stringA-stingB:stringC:stringD
stringN -stingB:stringC:stringD
stringN -stingB:stri:ngD
stringN stringA-stingB:stringD
```

I have following regex:

```
^(?<groupN>.*?)\s(?<groupA>.*?)?-(?<groupB>.*?):((?<groupC>.*?):)?(?<groupD>.*?)$
```

The issue occurs at scenario 3 (line 3) where there is ":" within capture group: "groupD" which makes that "stri" goes in capture group "groupC"
What I need is in scenario 3 to catch "stri:ngD" in groupD so no value for groupC.
Normally I was thinking for lookbehind with wildcard but I get error as wildcard is not supported in lookbehind, so is there any other way to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: What is the logic for deciding that a colon should not be treated as delimiter?

Comment: Its a log format so I know its like this, but as its is string , there can obviously be any char fx:":"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. Let me try asking it differently. What should happen with "abcd:efgh", or with "abcde:fghi", or with "abcdef:ghi", or with "abcdef:gh", .... When should the regex decide that group C should be empty, and when not?

Comment: good question but I don't have clear answer and I can see what you mean. Its an API and I was told that groupA and groupC , they can be missing sometimes.
I just know  from the content that this scenario occurs as by the mening of the content but there is no other logic then that about how to decide whether its groupC

Comment: If you don't have an answer, how could we?

Comment: ok, lets say there is value "N/A"  for groupB whenever GroupC is missing. Will this help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an indication whether or not GroupC is supposed to match something or not.

In comments you said that it could be determined by the matched value for GroupB: if it is N/A then GroupC should not capture any characters. This you can do with a negative look behind.

Replace

```
((?<groupC>.*?):)?
```

...with:

```
((?<!N\/A:)(?<groupC>.*?):)?
```